# How does packetbuf work in ContikiOS if there's an incoming packet during a pending send?

Tags: c, embedded, iot, contiki

I have trouble understanding how to write asynchronous sending/receiving in Contiki. Suppose I am using the xmac layer, or any layer that is based on `packetbuf`. I am sending a message, or a list of packets. I start sending a message using `void(*send)(mac_callback_t sent_callback, void *ptr)`. This takes the message that is in the `global` buffer `packetbuf`, and tries to send it. Meanwhile while the send is pending (for example waiting for the other device to wake up or acknowledge the transmission), the device receives a packet from a third device.

Will this packet overwrite the packet waiting to be sent that is in the `packetbuf`? How should I handle this?

I thought that maybe you can't be trying to send a packets and listen for incoming packets, but then there is an obvious deadlock: 2 devices sending messages to each other at the same time.

I am porting a higher-level routing layer to Contiki. This is the second OS I am porting it to, but the previous OS didn't use a single buffer for both incoming and outgoing packets.

Answer (score 1):

The `packetbuf` is a space for short-term data and metadata storage. It's not meant to be used by code that blocks longer than a few timer ticks. If you can't send the packet immediately from your `send()` function, do not block there! You need to schedule a timer callback in the future and return `MAC_TX_DEFERRED`. To store packet data in between invocations of `send()`, use the `queuebuf` module.

The fact that there is a single `packetbuf` for both reception and transmission is not a problem, since the radio is a half-duplex communication medium anyway. It cannot both send and receive data at the same time. Similarly, a packet that is received is first stored in the radio chip's memory: it does not overwrite the `packetbuf`. Contiki interrupt handlers similarly never write to `packetbuf` directly. They simply wake up the rx handler process, which takes the packet from the radio chip and puts it in the `packetbuf`. Since one process cannot unexpectedly interrupt another, this operation is safe: a processing wanting to send a packet cannot interrupt the process reading another packet.

To summarize, the recommendations are:

1. Do not block in Contiki process context (this is a generic rule when programming this OS, not specific to this question).
2. Do not the expect the contents of `packetbuf` are going to be saved across yielding the execution in Contiki process context. Serialize to a `queuebuf` if you need this.
3. Do not access the `packetbuf` from interrupt context.